# How can I delete all Time Machine backups of a given folder?

Tags: macos, time-machine, high-sierra

The `delete all backups of` dialog isn’t present when I right-click the folder in question.

I am trying to delete **all** Time Machine backups of this folder including the ones found in the local snapshots.

Comment: You question is ambiguous.  Are you trying to delete a specific folder, or 'all Time Machine backups' and 'local snapshots'?

Comment: I am trying to delete a specific folder.

Comment: Is this a folder in your (or another) user's space, or elsewhere (in System, Library, etc?)

Comment: It’s a folder in my user space `~`.

Answer (score 2):

You must enter Time Machine by going to the menu icon and clicking on it. One of the options is to "Enter Time machine". This will bring up all your backups on the screen. When I right click on a folder I get the options shown below.

[image]

[image]

If you chose "Delete All Folders " it should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. The problem is that the `delete all backups of` is not present in that menu (for reference, I am in Time Machine).

Comment: Maybe the folder is not in any other backups. Have you tried right clicking and on folders in other backups?